# Python / BeautifulSoup - Extracting XML data from clinicaltrials.gov, only able to extract studies that don't have missing data

Tags: python, pandas, xml, beautifulsoup, text-parsing

I am using clinicaltrials.gov's API to obtain a list of clinical trial data into a XML file and then I am parsing the data to eventually export into an Excel dataset.

In the URL provided in my code, there are 9 results, however my code is only pulling data for 5/9.  I've realized it's because that for one of the fields (*detaileddescription*), only some of the trials have this data. When I remove *detaileddescription* and just use the two other fields (nctid and *briefdescription*), I am able to get 9/9.  What can I do here besides doing something messy like creating a separate dataframe for *detaileddescription* and merging?

**Bottom line**: I am extracting 3 fields from an XML file that includes 9 clinical trials: *nctid*, *briefsummary*, and *detaileddescription*, but my output is only extracting 5/9 clinical trials.  How can my output get all 9/9 without taking out the *detaileddescription* field from my output?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

out = []
url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/full_studies?expr=diabetes+telehealth+peer+support&+AREA%5BStartDate%5D+EXPAND%5BTerm%5D+RANGE%5B01%2F01%2F2020%2C+09%2F01%2F2020%5D&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=50&fmt=xml'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
nctids = soup.find_all("field", {"name" : "NCTId"})
briefsummaries = soup.find_all("field", {"name" : "BriefSummary"}) if soup.find_all("field", {"name" : "BriefSummary"}) is not None else 'nothing'
detaileddescriptions = soup.find_all("field", {"name" : "DetailedDescription"}) if soup.find_all("field", {"name" : "DetailedDescription"}) is not None else 'nothing'

for nctid, briefsummary, detaileddescription in zip(nctids, briefsummaries, detaileddescriptions):
    
    data = {'nctid': nctid, 'briefsummary': briefsummary, 'detaileddescription': detaileddescription}
    out.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(out)

df.to_excel('clinicaltrialstresults.xlsx')
```

Comment: How many items are in nctid and briefsummary? My guess is that the zip you loop over is stopping at the end of the shortest zipped vector (detaileddescriptions).

Comment: nctid and briefsummary have just one entry per clinical trial and 9/9 in the XML file of the trials have these data.  Only 5/9 have the detaileddescriptions.  If this were SQL, I'd just make them into two tables and do a left join or something, but I'm assuming there's something I can do with the zip here (even if I can put some kind of dummy response)...

Comment: Second, at one time dictionaries did not gaurantee order (though I think this might have changed?), So you may not be associating the correct id/summary/descriptions with each other by separately creating dictionaries. Can you find one level up of tag, and create single objects with 3 attributes?

Comment: If it's giving you an xml file, maybe read it into a pandas dataframe directly (df.read_xml(response))?

Comment: Ugh, good point.  I didn't think about the possibility of these being disassociated.

Comment: I'm embarrassed that I didn't even know Pandas could easily import XML files.  Maybe that would be easiest.

Comment: It's new-ish, no worries. Other xml->python libraries (lxml) might work as intermediaries too, if you can't wrangle beautiful soup, eg: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python-with-pandas/

Comment: This is a huge help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looping over the study list with slight changes to your code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


out = []
url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/full_studies?expr=diabetes+telehealth+peer+support&+AREA%5BStartDate%5D+EXPAND%5BTerm%5D+RANGE%5B01%2F01%2F2020%2C+09%2F01%2F2020%5D&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=50&fmt=xml'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
study_list = soup.find_all("fullstudy")

for study in study_list:
    nctid = study.find("field", {"name" : "NCTId"})
    briefsummary = study.find("field", {"name" : "BriefSummary"}) if study.find("field", {"name" : "BriefSummary"}) is not None else 'nothing'
    detaileddescription = study.find("field", {"name" : "DetailedDescription"}) if study.find("field", {"name" : "DetailedDescription"}) is not None else 'nothing'
    data = {'nctid': nctid, 'briefsummary': briefsummary, 'detaileddescription': detaileddescription}
    out.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df.to_excel('clinicaltrialstresults.xlsx', index=False)
```